# Edit TextBox's Header property inside Style

Tags: textbox, windows-runtime

How to customize TextBox's Header property inside Styles for WinRT.

I want to change Header's FontSize & ForeGround property Inside a style.

I tried this:

```
<Style x:Name="valueTextBoxPortraitStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource valueTextBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="6"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10"/>
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="10" Foreground="Green"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But it gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added HeaderTemplate as an property & it solved the problem.

```
<Style x:Name="valueTextBoxPortraitStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource valueTextBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="6"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Purple"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```